# Get Firefox to ignore shortcut Ctrl+W for "close window", and use it for "close tab"

Tags: shortcut-keys, firefox

I currently use `ctrl+w` for closing application windows. `ctrl+w` is also Firefox's shortcut for closing a tab.

Is it possible to keep both, so therefore ignoring the global shortcut for `ctrl+w` when Firefox is focused?

I regularly have this sort of problem with keyboard shortcut clashes with at least one program, so any solution to get an application to ignore a shortcut is highly valuable.

Comment: Interesting question, but this is not possible a.f.a.i.k. Global shortcuts take precedence over these defined at the level of the application, and there is no way I know to change that,

Comment: I am using ctrl+q for close window now. Some applications natively recognize ctrl+w for close window, rather than application. Try it on document preview. Not sure it is recognized in all apps though.

Comment: Many applications including firefox use Ctrl+q to quit the application. You indeed can override that with a systemwide shortcut that closes the current window. I disable the Ctrl+q shortcut altogether because it is in my opinion too easily triggered. It is the classical Alt+F4 for me.

Answer (score 1):

go to `about:config` in firefox, and set `browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab` to `false`

that will make `ctrl+w` to close the last tab but keep browser open.

Answer (score 0):

It is often possible to set shortcuts within applications for e.g. close window. For example, for closing a terminal window like a firefox tab, try opening a terminal and right-clicking for `Preferences`, then `Shortcuts`, and setting `Close Window` to `ctrl-w`.

Then you can globally set close window in Ubuntu to something else (like `ctrl-q`), and Firefox can use `ctrl-w` for closing tabs.